Jupyterlite ImportError: cannot import name 'TypeAliasType' from 'typing_extensions' (/lib/python3.11/site-packages/typing_extensions.py)
On Jupyterlite, any cell I am trying to run never finishes loading in the notebook.
I use Chrome as a browser and if I open the browser's development tool with F12 and look at the error, it says:
ImportError: cannot import name 'TypeAliasType' from 'typing_extensions' (/lib/python3.11/site-packages/typing_extensions.py)
I have tried restarting the pyodide kernel, using another browser (Brave), emptying the cache of my browser and specifying the jupyterlite-pyodide-kernel or !pip * upgrading pyodide etc. but nothing works.
Did anyone solve this issue?

!pip will not do anything in Jupyterlite. When Jupyterlite is working you need to use %pip install. Getting back to your issue...where are you using JupyterLite from? From the main JupyterLite page here (where you click to launch using the buttons next to  'Open demo in a new tab', I am seeing this issue about "Repository is read only" . I'm not seeing your issue and that seems to be referring to Python and not the Pyodide kernel for some reason.

When I go here and click on the badge 'try lite now' and then choose from the launcher to open a notebook with 'Python (Pyodide}'. it works without error after I give it significant time to let the kernel get started first when the notebook opens.

Also, you should be using %pip install in any modern notebook anywhere now as that was best practice in Jupyter since 2019 when the magic verison of the install commands were added, and now they are supported in JupyterLite and Google Colab, making them universal, as far as I know, with the consistency now benefiting all. See more about the modern install commands here. ...

The second paragraph here goes into more details about why the exclamation point may lead to issues in standard Jupyter on some users' machines and so that is one of the main reasons the magic variation was added in 2019.
